# Whats the most effective int on a 8-Bit Microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

The size of an int is defined by the compiler, not by the processor. Thats why e.g. int_8 exist. However, I was thought that usually int is the most effective datatype. Is this still true when e.g. working on a Atmega8?

Atmega8 uses 16bit as many smaller system do. But using a 8bit int would save me one fetch and execution wouldn't it?

Comment: `int` is not defined to be the most effective integer width, at all. There's nothing that even suggests that, but the C standard defines `int` **must** take at least the range 2⁻¹⁵ to 2¹⁵-1!
what does "effective" even mean? nice, if you can use an 8bit integer to represent the values you need, by all means, do, but really: what do you do once it can't? How do you measure effectiveness when it comes to having to do some awkward multi-int8_t arithmetics to *emulate* a 16bit word? So, this question as it is is slightly underdefined. Can you explain what use case you're considering?

Comment: I didn't meant most effective int width. I meant the compiler handels default int best. Forcing him to use a fixed special type like int16_t might slow things down or do not allow him to optimize optimally. Most good compiler today even try to optimize your pipeline in some degree. Thats why the thought us to stick with int when possible. I might should have asked if a 8 bit microcontroller handels an 8 bit int faster than a 16bit default int type. I assume it does becuase it needs to fetches for sure.

Comment: No, the compiler does not "handle `int` best". Who says that? That's wrong.

Comment: I mean of all number types. What else? Float^^?

Comment: what? that makes no sense. Your assumption makes no sense. No, `int` is not the "best-handleable numeric data type". That's simply not the case. Stop presuming it is.

Comment: Well then tell me. In which data type would you store a number to handle it most effectively? Lets assume you want a counter up to 100. What type do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85581/discussion-between-mr-sh4nnon-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: counter up to 100 < 2⁸: use `uint8_t`. Let the compiler handle the optimization. No matter how many bits your processor has.

Comment: using `int` here would be a waste, on any platform, by the way. Even on my 64 bit desktop CPU, using an 8 bit variable where sufficient allows my compiler to infer that 8bit arithmetics are sufficient, and thus, things can e.g. be optimized by parallelizing 16 operations in a single SSE4 instruction.

Comment: So the compiler is not able to optimize a counter variable which can only reach 100? Is that what you mean? I see why int8_t is more effevtive in this case. But we were told if we want the compiler to take care use int. If you use int8_t its fixed. Nothing to optimize here.

Comment: You forget that the math done on 16 bit variables is **different** than what is done with 8 bit variables. So, yes, there's a lot to optimize if you have a smaller bit width. Really, you're a programmer, not a compiler: use the data type that fits your data, nothing more, nothing less. It's easy as that.

Comment: Thats exactly why I'm asking... I'm not a compiler. I might not know that a variable never reach a number greater 100 when writing it down. The compiler might notice this. There might be 100 variables and it might be able to optimize the hell out of it. Years ago people had carefully to think about what they do. Today compiler do a lot of that for you. Using the int8_t doesn't allow anything else to be taken. I ask it that way: Would the data type int allow the compiler to make optimizations?

Comment: But if we're talking about the C types as we do right now: you **must** be the one to know how far your counter goes. Your programming language doesn't allow inference on that (C is not e.g. Python or Haskell). So, if you don't know whether your counter might go to 100 or 1000, well, you must use a data type that fits 1000; that's obvious and has nothing to do with potential for optimization.

Comment: In the rare case that your compiler, in a loop, can see that the loop will take no more than \$N\$ iterations, well, it can truncate the data type on its own, yes, **iff** it's that smart. (hint: AVR-gcc is really really behind on smartness; Atmel didn't do a great job keeping their gcc fork up to date with mainline GCC when it comes to smartness) But then, the appropriate data type would still be the one that fits the data.

Comment: **But we were told if we want the compiler to take care use int.** I don't know who told you this, but I assure you these were no compiler developers or optimization experts. These were probably people with access to a 1995's compiler, from a time where machines started to change from defaulting to 16bit word length to 32bit, and compilers weren't mature at all. (or people from 10 years before that; replace 16bit by 8bit and 32 by 16). I frankly don't care what you've been told; it has no basis in reality.

Comment: @MarcusMüller A historical note: Kernighan&Ritchie (1978) in chapter 2.2 suggest **int** "typically reflecting the natural size of integers on the host machine". They then go on to refine **int** to **short, long, unsigned** .  Very old stuff, of interest if you're using an ancient compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C and C++ standards (You didn't state which you use) have a number of requirements on the ranges that char, short, int, long and long long (in signed and unsigned variant) can represent. But these requirements leave a lot of options open, the exact mapping from those standard types to hardware types is compiler-dependent (and sometimes also on versions, command-line flags, etc.)

When programming for small embedded systems the use of these 'raw' types is not recommended because the relation to the size is complex. Better specify what you need and let the compiler/library decide how to handle that best.

When you need a specific size (for instance to match the memory layout of a message or a set of hardware registers, or - for unsigned only - you need modulo arithmetic) use the fixed size types: int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t, int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t. It is possible that one of these types doesn't exist and you get a compiler error, but as you need the exact type that is for the best.

When you need a variable for calculation choose the smalles type that can handle your range, but allow the compiler to choose a larger type: int_fast8_t, uint_fast8_t, etc. This gives the best of both worlds: on an AVR, int_fast8_t will be a byte, but on a Cortex (where handling 8-bit arithmetic would be slower and use more instructions) it would be 32 bits. On your desktop it might be 64 bit, if the CPU can handle that faster.

When you want tos tore integer values, and you want to use as little space as possible, use one of the int_leastN_t/uint_leastN_t types. The compiler will choose the smallest type that can store at least the bist you specified.

And PS: use char only for ASCII. Even when you use the raw types (you shouldn't, but even then), don't use char as a small integer, because you never know whether it is signed or unsigned. And vice versa, don't use one of those *_t types if you want to store an ACII value, that is what char is for.

So IMO all built-in ints should be deprecated, except for char (which shouln't have been an int in the first place).

Comment: Nice! Note that `int*_fast_t` and the like are C99; not quite sure they exist in C++ at all.

Comment: @MarcusMüller -- they're in C++. They come in through `<cstdint>`.

Comment: Nice! good to know.

Comment: wow okay didn't know that. thank you! are there any drawbacks when choosing such a int_fast8_t?

Comment: so they are in c99 too @MarcusMüller?

Comment: @Mr.Sh4nnon well, exactly as the standard says, you get a data type that *at least* fits 8 bit. If you need 8bit arithmetics, you might get in trouble when using that.

Comment: One thing that's often overlooked: `int8_t`, etc. require a particular register size; if the hardware doesn't support that size, the type won't be defined. So for general use, `int_least8_t` or `int_fast8_t`, etc., are preferred. It's only if you really have to have exactly that number of bits that you use `int8_t`. Of course, for embedded systems that's usually the case: you're matching a particular register size, so it's often appropriate to use the exact type.

Comment: @PeteBecker the later part of your comment is true and informative, but the first part is false.  `int8_t` is defined by typical standard includes even on machines that don't have registers that *small*.  And `int32_t` is defined for machines that don't have registers that *large*.

Comment: @ChrisStratton -- from the C99 standard, 7.20.1.1/3, Exact-width integer types: "These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits ... it shall define the corresponding typedef names." The preceding two paragraphs define the signed and unsigned types "with width N **and no padding bits**" (emphasis added). You may well be right that some compilers emulate these things with carefully designed (and inefficient) operations that imitate those exact sizes; nevertheless, they're not something you can rely on having.

Comment: But the end rule is still the same: if you need a specific size (for layout or for modulo arithmetic), use the fixed-size type.(If your compiler doesn't provide it, you're screwed anayway. OK, you could emulate it yoursef...) If not, use one of the fast types.

Comment: @ChrisStratton `int8_t` is optional unlike the others. `int8_t` doesn't need to be defined on for example some crappy exotic TI DSP with 16 bit bytes.

Comment: It's not required, but it is *usual*.  And that contradicts the false claim above that it would not be present if there were no matching register size.   Those TI DSP's typically have a 16-bit `char`   But more typical 32 bit processors of today have a usual 8-bit one, and typically their compilers do define an `int8_t`